# Is it possible to link bison's generated parser in a crystal project?

Tags: bison, crystal-lang

I'm new to `Crystal-lang` and I would like to know whether there is any possibility to link a bison's generated parser in a crystal project and, if there is, How could it be done?

Comment: @VitaliiElenhaupt BSON and Bison are different things

Comment: What do you mean precisely? I am referring to Bison-Yacc GNU project...

Comment: Crystal lets you call a C function, so there is no problem callng `yyparse`. But you would still have to write your semantic actions in C.

Comment: And how could I get my AST back after calling yyparse? Should I define something like a struct in my 'library' binding in Crystal?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to do this.
Bison and yacc main functions (`yyparse` and `yylex`) can be easily bound and called from Crystal with the provided sintax.
What is useful is to provide a C function in bison or yacc to set the parser/lexer up (eg. to set lexer source file).

The AST can be retrived as a `void` pointer and manipulated through further C functions that can be required from crystal too.

It is also possible to declare two function pointers in the C implementation for the AST to allocate/free memory, and they can be set from Crystal to 'connect' the GC through a procedure.